# Using randint() with a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Im revisiting this tutorial of classes from LPTHW:

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html

Im in the middle of the 'class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene)' and playing around with the while loop for the code guess and I tried doing it a bit different like this:

```
    code = randint(1,3)
    user_guess = raw_input("> ")        

    while user_guess != code:
        print "BZZZT!"
        print "Try again"
        user_guess = raw_input("> ")

    if user_guess == code:

        print "The door slides open and you grab the bomb"
        return 'the_bridge'
    else:
        print "The lock buzzes again and the Gothons charge in anc kill you"
        return 'death'
```

However this just seems to loop endlessly for me and I never get the right answer.

If I change the first line to this:

```
code = "%d" % randint(1,3)
```

it works just fine, but if I open the Python terminal and do the following:

```
x = randint(1,3)
```

x will then return a random int between 1 and 3 which is exactly what I was trying to make the program do but it didn't seem to work as I expected.

Im confused about why "%d" % is required in the program for it to work.

Comment: `user_guess` is a string.

Comment: Briefly: `user_guess = int(raw_input("> "))` or `user_guess = input("> ")` or `code = str(randint(1,3))`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: But not actually `user_guess = input("> ")` because teaching the newbies to use implicit `eval` is evil. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger - Who said I'm not evil? [>=}](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/16/Drevil_million_dollars.jpg)